# Error on application startup after adding pg_context to main.py

Tags: python, postgresql, aiohttp, aiopg

I make polls application from [docs](https://aiohttp-demos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#creating-connection-engine). Version of PostgreSQL is 15. Using poetry here are my dependencies from `pyproject.toml`:

```
python = "^3.11"
aiohttp = "^3.8.5"
aiodns = "^3.0.0"
pyyaml = "^6.0.1"
aiopg = {extras = ["sa"], version = "^1.4.0"}
```

main.py:

```
app.cleanup_ctx.append(pg_context) # Added this
```

db.py

```
async def pg_context(app):
    conf = app['config']['postgres']
    engine = await aiopg.sa.create_engine(
        database=conf['database'],
        user=conf['user'],
        password=conf['password'],
        host=conf['host'],
        port=conf['port'],
        minsize=conf['minsize'],
        maxsize=conf['maxsize'],
    )
    app['db'] = engine

    yield

    app['db'].close()
    await app['db'].wait_closed()
```

If I remove `app.cleanup_ctx.append(pg_context)` from `main.py` server runs successfully. But when I try to run server `python main.py` I got such error (see below): What problem can it be?

From traceback: it says exception occurs when I do this `engine = await aiopg.sa.create_engine(...` in db.py.

```
(aiohttp-example-py3.11) F:\python\AIOHTTP\polls>python app_polls/main.py
unhandled exception during asyncio.run() shutdown
task: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<_run_app() done, defined at C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web.py:289> exception=NotImplementedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web.py", line 516, in run_app
    loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web.py", line 323, in _run_app
    await runner.setup()
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_runner.py", line 279, in setup
    self._server = await self._make_server()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_runner.py", line 375, in _make_server
    await self._app.startup()
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_app.py", line 417, in startup
    await self.on_startup.send(self)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiosignal\__init__.py", line 36, in send
    await receiver(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_app.py", line 539, in _on_startup
    await it.__anext__()
  File "F:\python\AIOHTTP\polls\app_polls\db.py", line 32, in pg_context
    engine = await aiopg.sa.create_engine(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\sa\engine.py", line 94, in _create_engine
    pool = await aiopg.create_pool(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\pool.py", line 300, in from_pool_fill
    await self._fill_free_pool(False)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\pool.py", line 336, in _fill_free_pool
    conn = await connect(
                 ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\connection.py", line 65, in connect
    connection = Connection(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\connection.py", line 772, in __init__
    self._loop.add_reader(
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 530, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\python\AIOHTTP\polls\app_polls\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    web.run_app(app)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web.py", line 516, in run_app
    loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web.py", line 323, in _run_app
    await runner.setup()
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_runner.py", line 279, in setup
    self._server = await self._make_server()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_runner.py", line 375, in _make_server
    await self._app.startup()
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_app.py", line 417, in startup
    await self.on_startup.send(self)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiosignal\__init__.py", line 36, in send
    await receiver(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_app.py", line 539, in _on_startup
    await it.__anext__()
  File "F:\python\AIOHTTP\polls\app_polls\db.py", line 32, in pg_context
    engine = await aiopg.sa.create_engine(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\sa\engine.py", line 94, in _create_engine
    pool = await aiopg.create_pool(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\pool.py", line 300, in from_pool_fill
    await self._fill_free_pool(False)
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\pool.py", line 336, in _fill_free_pool
    conn = await connect(
                 ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\connection.py", line 65, in connect
    connection = Connection(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\connection.py", line 772, in __init__
    self._loop.add_reader(
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 530, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Exception ignored in: <function Connection.__del__ at 0x000001CF28EEC360>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\connection.py", line 1188, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\connection.py", line 995, in close
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\aiohttp-example-zDtRzW9K-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\aiopg\connection.py", line 977, in _close
  File "C:\Users\sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 533, in remove_reader
NotImplementedError:
```

Comment: Is that the *full* traceback?

Comment: No' it's not. it doesn't allow me to insert full. But I updated question and added a little bit more info from traceback.

Comment: Sorry, can't help without full traceback.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński added full traceback, now it allowed me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know whether it is a full traceback or not, but according to this there is **Not Implemented** Exception.

Might be because of:

1. The package version is not compatible with python version.
2. The function you are calling is not implemented.

Some searching lead me to [this](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg/issues/678#issuecomment-667908402). With referance to github comment, you can use this code(might help, have not recreated):

```
import sys, asyncio
if sys.version_info >= (3, 8) and sys.platform.lower().startswith("win"):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Comment: I asked on GitHub [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/discussions/7453#discussioncomment-6584759), I need to use SQLAlchemy 2.0 instead of 1.4 in aiopg, I think it'll take time for them to update tutorial in official docs.